# microdata schema.org: how to mix together schemas?

Tags: html, seo, microdata, schema.org

hello I have a page ( http://schema.org/WebPage ) that contains a review ( http://schema.org/Review )

the question are:

- how to deal with duplicate contents?
- is correct making elements belong to two or more scopes?
- how to do this, repeating text twice?
- or i should avoid multiple references?

example:

```
<html itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage">
    <meta name="description" content="_________" itemprop="description">
    ...
    <div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Review">
        <div itemprop="description">_________</div>
    </div>
    ...
</html>
```

the description belongs to the Review AND to the WebPage, so... what I should write in this case?

(note: in the previous example the string "***_*_**" is the same text paragraph, repeated twice)

---

EDIT:

can this be a solution? (the html5 spec doesn't talk about this, but defines the itemref attribute)

```
<html itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage" id="WEBPAGE">
    ...
    <div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Review" id="REVIEW">
        <div itemprop="description" itemref="WEBPAGE REVIEW">_________</div>
    </div>
    ...
</html>
```

FEEL FREE TO IMPROVE THE QUESTION!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

### Quick answers

- *how to deal with duplicate contents?*

  - **use the attribute itemref**
- *is correct making elements belong to two or more scopes?*

  - **Yes, this is what you use itemref for**
- *how to do this, repeating text twice?*

  - **No, you only need to refer to the element**
- *or i should avoid multiple references?*

  - **I don't see any reason why you don't wanna use multiple references**

---

### Some Examples

**Include by wrapping**

When you use the itemref attribute you include all property contained within the referred element to a different scope.

```
<body itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage" itemref="wrapper">
    ...
    <div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Review">
        ...
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div itemprop="description">_________</div>

            <div itemprop="some-other-property">_________</div>
        </div>
        ...
    </div>
    ...
</body>
```

**Include by wrapping - a different example**

Lets say you have a product with a few different offers outside the scope.

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product" itemref="wrapper">
    ...
</div>

<div id="wrapper">
    <div itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
        ...
    </div>

    <div itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
        ...
    </div>

    <div itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

**Include a specific property**

You might only wish to include one specific property outside the scope, to do this we can simply set the id directly on the targeted element with the itemprop specified.

```
<body itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage" itemref="target">
    ...
    <div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Review">
        <div id="target" itemprop="description">_________</div>
    </div>
    ...
</body>
```

**Multiple references**

Maybe a wrapper isn't applicable, then you can use multiple references. You separate them simply by space.

```
<body itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage" itemref="desc name">
    ...
    <div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Review">
        <div id="desc" itemprop="description">_________</div>

        <div id="name" itemprop="name">_________</div>
    </div>
    ...
</body>
```

---

### Source

See also thees pages for some other explanations and examples:
http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-microdata-20110405/
http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/microdata.html

Comment: why google rich snippet tool doesn't recognize the itemref attribute? thanks for your answer!

Comment: It's hard for me to answer for what Google does, my guess is that it has to do with the fact that it's in beta.

Comment: Hi @skyline26, Google detect my itemref. I think you have some problem elsewhere.

Comment: @Erik: Your example of "Multiple references" is problematic.  In most cases it seems like you would want to specify them by class name, not ID.  For instances, it's easy to imagine a page that has a _long_ list of reviews - listing the id of each one would not be desirable...

Comment: @doub1ejack: what I can see from whatwg.org there is no way to specify by class name: http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/microdata.html#attr-itemref   
*"The itemref attribute, if specified, must have a value that is an unordered set of unique space-separated tokens that are case-sensitive, consisting of IDs of elements in the same home subtree."*
  
I will attempt to update the answer with some additional information addressing the issue you described though.

Comment: @doub1ejack: I added an update to address the problem you described under **Include by wrapping - a different example**. Have a look and let me know if you have any questions.